Interpretation of IR spectrum
I was trying to identify the following IR spectrum as part of an exercise sheet of my spectroscopy course. 
What I know from the spectrum, is that we have broad OH stretching vibrations at $\pu{3200-3600 cm-1}$ which indicate the presence of an alcohol function. I can be certain that the sample was not contaminated with water. Furthermore, the $\ce{C-H}$ stretching peak is at around $\pu{2970 cm-1}$, it looks like there is only one $\ce{C-H}$ functionality; furthermore, at $\pu{1050 cm-1}$ there is a peak, indicating a substitution pattern.
My first thought is that it would be an aromatic compound, however, the $\ce{C-H}$ stretch vibrations would appear at wavenumbers higher than $\pu{3000 cm-1}$, so this structure won't be it, probably. I also thought about an chlorosubsituted propanol, but the peak at $\pu{1050 cm-1}$ would be $\ce{C-F}$ vibrations, so I can't be certain for that. Do you have any other ideas?

Squalene isn't aromatic, nor cyclic; only C, H but no O, nor F. Is there a particular reason to plot it (I presume) with Origin, instead with the manufacturer's software (example Thermo)? Ask for a better one: the humps to negative absorption ($\approx 2900$, $\pu{1100 cm-1}$) and drifting baseline (le $\pu{750 cm-1}$) merit a new recording. The thing around $\pu{500 cm-1}$ is a bit too narrow to be a band of a liquid film.

For comparison: SDBS has an entry with a recorded IR spectrum: https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/landingpage?sdbsno=36179 as thin film, recorded either on a Nicolet (now part of ThermoScientific), or a JASCO; see the database's introduction.  While there is some shoulder to wavelengths le 750 wavenumbers, it doesn't appear as strong as in your example.  And more importantly, no negative absorption, no sudden «spikes» (like what happened around $\pu{1000 cm-1}$?  [irony on:] A Truck was passing the lab? [irony off])
